# Not able to connect to outlook.com SMTP using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, ssl, outlook, smtp, nodemailer

I am creating the transport object like this.

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
        host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
        secureConnection: false, // use SSL
        port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
        auth: {
            user: "user@outlook.com",
            pass: "password"
        }
    });
```

This is the error which I am getting, when I try to send the mail.

> [Error: 139668100495168:error:1408F10B:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version
>   number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:337: ]

When I tried setting ignoreTLS as true. This is what I am getting

> { [AuthError: Invalid login - 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command
>   first]   name: 'AuthError',   data: '530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first' }

Am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I was having the same issue until I stumbled upon https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/issues/165

Try adding the tls cipher option to use SSLv3.

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", // hostname
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
    auth: {
        user: "user@outlook.com",
        pass: "password"
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }
});
```

Alternatively, for hotmail/live/outlook you can simply use

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "hotmail",
    auth: {
        user: "user@outlook.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you forgot to remove the first argument, "SMTP", in your `service:"hotmail"` example.

Comment: @michalstanko's comment is no longer valid. You no longer require `SMTP` as the first argument

Comment: I was hitting my head against the wall with Gmail SMTP Configuration and just realized Outlook could be much easier. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 4):

```
let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "Outlook365",
  host: "smtp.office365.com",
  port: "587",
  tls: {
    ciphers: "SSLv3",
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
  auth: {
    user: "**********",
    pass: "*******",
  },
});
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: "********", // sender address
  to: to, // list of receivers
  subject: subject, // Subject line
  html: html, // html body
});

You can use thing configuration for nodemailer with outlook account
```

Answer (score 1):

basically, error from `SSLv3`, so i have the solution from my

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',                  // hostname
    service: 'outlook',                             // service name
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3'                            // tls version
    },
    port: 587,                                      // port
    auth: {
        user: "<Your Email>",
        pass: "<Password>"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nodemailer 1.x or greater you can use:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtp://username%40outlook.com:password@smtp-mail.outlook.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using v5+**

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com", 
  secureConnection: false, 
  port: 587, 
  service: "outlook",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_ID,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
  tls: {
    ciphers: "SSLv3",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its worked for me in Nodemailer version 6.9.1 and have not any issue with typescript

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
  port: 587,
  tls: {
    ciphers: "SSLv3",
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
  auth: {
    user: "the  your username",
    pass: "the your pass",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in Nodemailer version 6.9.1 and have not any issue with typescript.

Just remove `secureConnection: false` and add `rejectUnauthorized: false` to tls object.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
  port: 587,
  tls: {
    ciphers: "SSLv3",
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
  auth: {
    user: "the  your username",
    pass: "the your pass",
  },
});
```

Answer (score -3):

tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    }
+1  working

and for first agr ("SMTP",  is not support later version . one will have to downgrade nodemailler