# Nodemailer - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: node.js, email, security, firewall, nodemailer

I am trying to send a email using Nodemailer with these configurations :

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
          host: 'smtp.outlookhost',
          port: 25,
          auth: {
            user: '',
            pass: ''
          },
          secure:false,
          logger: true,
          debug: true
        }));
```

I am getting this error :

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I am using outlook to send email. How can I provide certificates.

Modified the configurations :

```
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
              host: 'smtp.outlookhost',
              port: 25,
              auth: {
                user: '',
                pass: ''
              },
              secure:true,
              logger: true,
              debug: true,
              tls: {
              // do not fail on invalid certs
              rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
    }));
```

Error :

```
Error: 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c
```

Answer (score 8):

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.outlookhost",
    port:  25,
    secure: false,
    tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
  });
```

Late answer, but this worked for me using the current version of nodemailer and an outlook host.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help you:
[Not able to connect to outlook.com SMTP using Nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509357/not-able-to-connect-to-outlook-com-smtp-using-nodemailer)

I would use the second approach, as it is easier! =D

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "hotmail",
    auth: {
        user: "user@outlook.com",
        pass: "password"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case nodemailer couldn't find our corporate CA certificate. So I set ca option and it solved the issue. CA cert is in PEM format and begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp-server',
  port: 25,
  tls: {
    ca: [ fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ca.pem')) ],
  },
});
```